# Jquery Issue with validation

Tags: jquery

I have question below
I have profile page contains user_name ,email,city etc...
when performing validation i will check user_name already existing or not and other regular stuff like emmail validation,integer check etc...
My problem is user_name check is a ajax call so beofre completing the user_name check validation is completed and inserted wrong user name that already existed..how can i prevent this.

my code is below

```
function doValidation()
{   
var err = '0' ;
var errWebuser='0';
if($('#FHE_0_user_name').val()!="")
    {
    alert("call check");
    errWebuser=checkWebUserName('FHE_0_user_name');
    alert(errWebuser);
    }
$('.required input').each(function(){
    if(  ($(this).val() == '')  )
    {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        err = '1';
        $(this).css('border','1px solid #F00');
        appendError(id,'required');

    }
```

in that checkWebUserName is the ajax call

thanks alex

Comment: You have asked 5 questions and couldn't be bothered to accept an answer to any one of them. Fix that, or you'll find people won't be keen to help you out

Answer (score 0):

Perform all client side validation first, if all pass, perform server side validation and creation in single db transaction.  Read up on db transactions. You don't want to mix in client and server side validations in the same step.

Comment: If i do in that way also same problem,like ajax return value is coming faster before executing the ajax function